# Vertical alignment of subfigures

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, subfloats, pstricks, pst-tree

So I have a document which in a lot of places uses one pstree (part of the pstricks package) and a simple tabular side by side...I do this with subfigures. The problem is that because the pstree image is bigger than the table there is much empty space under the table. I want the table to be vertically centered according to the height of the pstree. Is there a way to do this?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}

\subfigure {
    PSTree code
}

\hspace{40pt}

\subfigure {
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}    
        The Table
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{center}

\caption{The caption for both}
\label{mylabel:1}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code shows two options; the first one uses `minipages` and the second one uses the `subfigure` and `subtable` environments from the `subcaption` package; the alignment is achieved by using the optional argument of the environments (I used a black rectangle to simulate the tree):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{7cm}% to simulate the tree
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[C]{c|c|c|}    
      column1a & column2a & column3a \\
      column1b & column2b & column3b
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{The caption for both}
  \label{mylabel:1}
\end{figure}

% requires the subcaption and the caption packages
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \begin{subfigure}[c]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{7cm}% to simulate the tree
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[C]{c|c|c|}    
      column1a & column2a & column3a \\
      column1b & column2b & column3b
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{The caption for both}
  \label{mylabel:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: the `subfigure` package is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore. A good replacement is the `subcaption` package (although in this particular case there seems to be no need to use it since no separate caption is required for the tree and the table; standard `minipages` can do the job).